# Cannot use git to clone in remote web server

Tags: github, ssh

I have created a Github repo to where I push my local changes using Git Bash, without any problems. I can also use Git Bash to connect to my remote web server (shared hosting) and navigate to the folder where I want to clone my Laravel site.
This is where the problems begin. When I do

```
$ git clone git@github.com:myusername/mylaravelsite.git
```

I get the error message:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

After some searching for a solution I found that I should make sure that I have a key by doing this:

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Which gave this answer:

```
Agent pid 122372
```

Then according to the instructions I should do this

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

Which gave me this message:

```
The agent has no identities
```

Reading up a bit more I try to add the key again by doing

```
$ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

...which generated a key pair that I added with `ssh-add`, I was prompted for a passphrase which I entered twice.

Now, I still get Permission denied (publickey) when I try to access my github repo with ssh. I should also mention that I have created a new SSH key at the github account where I pasted the key I created (I opened .ssh/id_rsa-pub with notepad and copied the content).

What more can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer in case anyone else has the same problem. It turns out that the public key also must exist in the remote web server (in the .ssh folder I uploaded the same rsa_id and rsa_id.pub files, that I created locally), not only locally and in the Github account.

Once I had figured that out and uploaded those files to the webserver, it worked to clone my github repo :-).